# How do I sum sub-totals fields to calculate grand total?

Tags: javascript

I have a form for the item, quantity, price fields which user dynamically adds or deletes. Now I want to add sub totals and the grand totals to the form.

Until now, I have been able to use the following code, but this just subtotals for the first row and not for the rest of the rows, and also grand total is also required.

Javascript:

```
function totalprice()
{
    a = document.form1.quantity.value
    b = document.form1.price.value

    c = a * b

    document.form1.total.value = c
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="here.php" method="post" name="form1">
    Quantity: <input name="quantity" size="10">Price: <input name="price" size="10" onblur="totalprice();"><br>
    Total: <input name="total" size="10" readonly=true><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make your grand total function or is your question in the title?

Comment: Don't forget to add a semi-colon to the end of each statement in JavaScript, otherwise you're certain to run into problems at some point.

Comment: @Vache hi, i tried posting this but by error the subject was taken from a previous draft. sorry for that. i am looking for grand total without refresh for subtotals of all rows(that are dynamically populated based on user's input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no other forms:

```
function SetTotals()
{

// Overall total.
var total = 0;

//  Get all forms for individual items.
var formArray = document.getElementsByTagName("form");

//  Loop all forms setting the total foreach item and incrementing the total value.
for (var i in formArray)
{
var form = formArray[i];

// Set value total value for this form.
form.total.value = form.quantity.value * form.price.value;

// Increment total for all forms.
total += form.total.value;
}

// All forms looped that total obtained, set it on the total value element.
document.getElementById("<The total element id>").value = total;
}
```

As usual with my answers I haven't tested it but the principle is correct. If you have other types of forms in the document then a single if check for the correct type of form should be done (perhaps it should be done anyway).

Comment: @Vinnyq12 hi. i am using the following code for subtotals.
function totalprice()
{
len=document.forms["main"]["qty[]"].length;
if (len==undefined){
var a = document.forms["main"]["qty[]"].value;
var b = document.forms["main"]["price[]"].value;
var c = a * b;
var d = c.toFixed(2);
document.forms["main"]["total[]"].value = d;
} else
{
for(h=0;h<len;h++) {
var a = document.forms["main"]["qty[]"][h].value;
var b = document.forms["main"]["price[]"][h].value;
var c = a * b;
var d = c.toFixed(2);
document.forms["main"]["total[]"][h].value = d;
}
}
}
appreciate if you can explain in relevance to this

Comment: @mmdel if you also post a sample of the complete form that this JS function is being used against I will be able to help better.

Comment: @Vinnyq21
@Vache
@Andy E

i am posting the link to how far i have gone with this. pl. help me out with the grand total field. also, suggest me if i am doing anything wrong or the same can be done in a better way.

http://jsfiddle.net/mmarwaha/fdWQa/5/

Comment: @vinnyq12
hi, here is the code that i have come up with but with errors.
<script type="text/javascript">
function totalprice()
{
 len = document.forms["form1"]["quantity[]"].length;
 
 for(i=0;i<len;i++){
a = document.forms["form1"]["quantity[]"][i].value;
b = document.forms["form1"]["price[]"][i].value
 
c = a * b
 
document.forms["form1"]["total[]"][i].value = c;
 sum = 0;
 for (b=0;b<len;b++){
  var d = document.forms["form1"]["total[]"][b].value;
  var sum = sum + d;
  document.forms["form1"]["grandtotal"].value = sum;
 }
 
}

}
</script>

Comment: @mmdel, sorry but it is hard for me to say whats wrong without seeing the HTML as well.